# Solving PDE for a parametric function, using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I've to solve a $4 \times 4$ matrix PDE which involves the following matrices:

```
Mp[r_] = {{-kx Sqrt[1/r^2] - Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 + Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r + ω), 
        -2 I (1 - 1/r), -ky Sqrt[1/r^2], 0}, {2 I (1 - 1/r), kx Sqrt[1/r^2] 
        + Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 - Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r - ω), 0, -ky Sqrt[1/r^2]},
        {ky Sqrt[1/r^2], 0, -kx Sqrt[1/r^2] - Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 - 
        Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r + ω), -2 I (1 - 1/r)}, 
        {0, ky Sqrt[1/r^2], 2 I (1 - 1/r), kx Sqrt[1/r^2] + 
        Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 + Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r - ω)}}

Mn[r_] = {{-kx Sqrt[1/r^2] - Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 - Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r + ω), 
        -2 I (1 - 1/r), ky Sqrt[1/r^2], 0}, {2 I (1 - 1/r), kx Sqrt[1/r^2] +
        Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 + Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r - ω), 0, ky Sqrt[1/r^2]}, 
        {-ky Sqrt[1/r^2], 0, -kx Sqrt[1/r^2] - Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 + Sqrt[r^2] (1 
        - 1/r + ω), -2 I (1 - 1/r)}, {0, -ky Sqrt[1/r^2], 2 I (1 -1/r),
        kx Sqrt[1/r^2] + Sqrt[r^4]/r^2 - Sqrt[r^2] (1 - 1/r - ω)}}

kk = √(kx^2 + ky^2);

GIR = DiagonalMatrix[{ -( √(kk + ω)/√(kk - \
      ω)) ,  √(kk - ω)/√(kk + ω),  \
      √(kk - ω)/√(kk + ω), -( √(kk + \
      ω)/√(kk - ω)) }]
```

I'm trying solve for a 3-parameter (`kx, ky, ω`) function $G$ using the following PDE. Note `GIR` defined above gives a boundary condition for $r$ close to zero, since $r=0$ is singularity I've kept it $0.001$). The PDE is

```
soln = ParametricNDSolve[{G'[r] == Mp[r] - G[r].Mn[r].G[r], G[0.001] == GIR},
       G, {r, 1, 10}, {kx, ky, ω}] 
G[kx, ky, ω][r] /. soln
```

After running this code, when I evaluate e.g. `G[2, 1, 1, 0.001]` I get back `G[2, 1, 1, 0.001]` ; I can't figure out why $G$ is not being evaluated. In fact the final quantity of my interest is:

```
M[r_, kx_, ky_, ω_] := Tr[Im[Evaluate[G[kx, ky, ω][r] /. soln]]]
ContourPlot[M[r, kx, 0, 0], {kx, 0, 5}, {r, 1, 10}, FrameLabel -> {"k", "Tr[Im M]"}]
```

But this gives an empty plot. Any kind of help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
G[r_] := Array[g[##][r] &, {4, 4}]
soln = ParametricNDSolve[
  Join[Thread[ Flatten@Array[g[##]'[r] &, {4, 4}] == Flatten[Mp[r] -G[r].Mn[r].G[r]]], 
   Thread[Flatten@G[.001] == Flatten@GIR]],
  Flatten[Array[g[##] &, {4, 4}]],
  {r, .001, 10}, {kx, ky, ω}]

g[1, 2][1, 2, 3][1] /. soln
(*-3.58322*10^-17 + 0.22098 I*)
```

The following is probably numerical noise:

```
M[r_?NumericQ, kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ, ω_?NumericQ] := 
 Tr[Re[Evaluate[Array[g[##][kx, ky, ω][r] &, {4, 4}] /. soln]]]
ContourPlot[M[r, kx, 0, 0], {kx, 0, 5}, {r, 1, 10}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "Tr[Im M]"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful yet I still get a blank graph only.

Comment: @Skylar15 There are other problems. For certain parameters your system is stiff. For others the solution involves complex numbers.My code is just a start for you to be able to get some numerical output

Comment: @Skylar15 See edit

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I am trying to take care of the singularities and numerical noises. For those I've to fix some other parameters. Appreciate your effort!